# How to write every Json property into a List without its content

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I have a .Json file like this:

```
{
   "Main":{
      "Funktion":{
         "Sub1":"",
         "Sub2":{
            "something1":"",
            "something2":"",
            "something3":""
         },
         "Sub3":{
            "something4":""
         },
         "Sub4":{
            "something5":""
         },
         "Sub5":{
            "something6":""
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Now i want to write every "SubX" into a List or Array but without the text within each Sub.

So it will look like this

OUTPUT:

```
Printed List:
"Sub1"
"Sub2"
"Sub3"
"Sub4"
"Sub5"
```

I´ve already made it with converting to a String and via String handle.
Now i wonder if there is a more elegant solution for this problem.

Comment: Are you using Json.Net or System.Text.Json?

Comment: Json.net. I edited it

Comment: In case of Json.Net  you can get those names like this: `JObject.Parse(json)["Main"]["Funktion"].Children().Select(x => ((JProperty)x).Name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to retrieve only the names of the `Funktion` sub-nodes is the following:

```
JObject.Parse(json)["Main"]["Funktion"].Children().Select(x => ((JProperty)x).Name)
```

- With `JObject.Parse` we same parse the json
- With `["Main"]["Funktion"]` we travers through the nodes
- With `.Children()` we ask for the sub-nodes (`JToken`s)
- With `.Select` we cast the `JToken` to `JProperty` to be able to get the `Name` property

---

I want to emphasize that this approach is error-prone. It highly relies on actual structure. In order to make it more robust please consider to use [`TryGetValue`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_TryGetValue.htm) instead of index operator.